# Bootstrap tabs switching on button click doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I need to switch between bootstrap tabs on a button click event(if some condition in click event is satisfied ) and so on .However It is not working.I have been trying various ways but nothing worked .If I remove the updatepanel in first tab it works , but I don't want the entire page to be refreshed.Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks in advance.Below is my code.`

```
  <div id="Left" class="w3-container city w3-animate-Zoom" style="display: none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"  style="width:100%;margin-top:50px">
        <div class="tab" id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
     <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="TabList" role="tablist" runat="server">
                <li id="result1" role="presentation"  runat="server"><a href="#Section7" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Patient Information</a></li>
                <li id="result2" role="presentation"   runat="server" ><a href="#Section8"  aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Financially Responsible Party</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"  ><a href="#Section9" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Emergency Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content tabs">
<!-- Patient Information -->
                 <div  role="tabpanel"  runat="server"  id="Section7">
                 <table  width="100%" align="center" >
                 <tr><td colspan="4">
                 <table width="100%"  class="w3-card w3-table w3-small">
                 <tr>
                 <td>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel16" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>
  <table width="100%"  class="w3-card w3-table w3-small">
  <tr><td ><label  >Patient Name&nbsp; </label><asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" TabIndex="7"  ID="txt_PatientName"  runat="server" ValidationGroup="ADD"  Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
  </td><td align="left"><label  >Contact Number </label>
  <asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_Cnumber" TabIndex="8" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ADD"  Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td  colspan="4"  style="text-align:right" align="right"><asp:Button 
      ID="but_Submit" runat="server" Text="Register" ValidationGroup="ADD" 
       CssClass="w3-btn w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-hover-red"
                                            OnClick="but_Submit_Click" 
        TabIndex="23"></asp:Button>
        </td>
</tr>
     </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
             <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="but_Submit" 
              EventName="Click" />
              </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
        </td></tr>
   </table>
                       </div>
                 <!-- Financially Responsible Party -->
                 <div role="tabpanel"  runat="server" id="Section8">
                 <table  width="100%" align="center" >
                 <tr><td colspan="4">
                <table width="100%"  class="w3-card w3-table w3-small">
                <tr><td ><label  >Financial Bearer Name&nbsp; </label> 
                <asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" 
                TabIndex="7"  ID="txt_fbname"  runat="server" 
      ValidationGroup="ADD1"  Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
      </td><td align="left"><label  >Relation to Patient  </label>
      <asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_rtp" 
      TabIndex="8" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ADD1"  Width="200px"> 
      </asp:TextBox>
         </td>
        <td align="left" ><label  >Date of Birth </label><asp:TextBox 
     class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_fbdob" runat="server" 
     TabIndex="15" ValidationGroup="ADD1" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
     <cc1:CalendarExtender CssClass= "cal_Theme1" ID="CalendarExtender1" 
     runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
     PopupButtonID="txt_fbdob" TargetControlID="txt_fbdob"> 
     </cc1:CalendarExtender>
    </td>
         <td align="left"><label >Occupation</label><asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_occptn" runat="server"  TabIndex="20" ValidationGroup="ADD1" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>

        </tr>
   <tr>
     <td  colspan="4"  style="text-align:right" align="right"><asp:Button 
      ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="SAVE" ValidationGroup="ADD" 
      CssClass="w3-btn w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-hover-red"
      OnClick="but_Submit1_Click" TabIndex="23"></asp:Button>
          </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
       </div>
       <!--End Financially Responsible Party -->
                 <!--Emergency Contact -->
                 <div role="tabpanel"  class="tab-pane fade" id="Section9">       
      <table  width="100%" align="center" >
      <tr><td colspan="4">   
      <table width="100%"  class="w3-card w3-table w3-small">
    <tr><td ><label  >Contact Name&nbsp; </label><asp:TextBox class="w3- 
    input w3-border w3-round" TabIndex="7"  ID="txt_emname"  runat="server" 
     ValidationGroup="ADD2"  Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
      </td><td align="left"><label  >Relation to Patient  </label>
      <asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_emrtp" 
      TabIndex="8" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ADD2"  Width="200px"> 
      </asp:TextBox>
         </td>
       <td align="left"><label >Mobile Number&nbsp; </label><asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_emmob" runat="server"  TabIndex="12" ValidationGroup="ADD2" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
          </td><td ><label >Office Phone </label><asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_emofpnum" TabIndex="13" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ADD2" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    <td align="left" ><label>Home Phone&nbsp; </label><asp:TextBox class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" ID="txt_emhmpnum" runat="server"  TabIndex="14" ValidationGroup="ADD2" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>

        </tr>
    <tr>
     <td  colspan="4"  style="text-align:right" align="right"><asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="SAVE" ValidationGroup="ADD" CssClass="w3-btn w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-hover-red"
                                            OnClick="but_Submit2_Click" TabIndex="23"></asp:Button>
        </td>
</tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
                       </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
Page Load Event
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            username = Session["user"].ToString();

        }
        result1.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        Section7.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane active");
        //hide the  tab (menu and content)
        Section8.Attributes.Remove("class");
        Section8.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane");
        result2.Attributes.Remove("class");
        result2.Attributes.Add("class", "nav nav-tabs");
        ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btn_CoverttoPDF);
    }
Button Click Event
protected void but_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //code for inserting data//
         //switching code
         result2.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
         Section8.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane active");
         //hide the personal tab (menu and content)
         Section7.Attributes.Remove("class");
         Section7.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane");
         result1.Attributes.Remove("class");
         result1.Attributes.Add("class", "nav nav-tabs");
     }
```

`

Comment: You can do all the stuff that you´re doing in the Button's server side click handler on a javascript function and remove the update panel entirely.

Comment: @Martin Could you please show an example  Since I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            $(".nav-tabs a").click(function () {
                $(this).tab('show');
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

See an example below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="width:100%;margin-top:50px">
        <div class="tab" id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="TabList" role="tablist" runat="server">
                <li id="result1" role="presentation" runat="server"><a href="#Section7" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Patient Information</a></li>
                <li id="result2" role="presentation" runat="server"><a href="#Section8" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Financially Responsible Party</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section9" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Emergency Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="onButtonClick()">Register</button>
</div>

<script>
    function onButtonClick() {
        document.getElementById('result2').classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById('Section8').classList.add("tab-pane active");
        //hide the personal tab (menu and content)
        document.getElementById('Section7').className = '';
        document.getElementById('Section7').classList.add("tab-pane");
        document.getElementById('result1').className = '';
        document.getElementById('result1').classList.add("nav nav-tabs");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is not working for me . Still the page refreshes and remains in the same tab.

Comment: I don't want the page to be refreshed because I have many sidebars and when the page refreshes it goes to the default sidebar menu form .That's why I have used update panel in Registration form to avoid refreshing .

Comment: I just want to be in the same page but next tab . Any help will be really appreciated.